# Blender to Unreal Engine import animation troubleshooting - Alembic files looks jagged

Tags: animation, unreal-engine, alembic

Apologies that this issue is primarily regarding Unreal, but I was wondering if any Blender-to-Unreal users have come across this issue when exporting an animated mesh as an alembic into Unreal. Below are screenshots of the mesh in Blender vs. Unreal, importing this alembic into Unreal looks extremely jagged. The animation still works in Unreal, it's just the mesh quality that I want to correct. I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction in regards to settings/checkboxes I should be looking out for, or mesh quality I should be aiming towards? The mesh in Blender is all quads, and all quads are relatively square in proportion for the most part. I am familiar with exporting alembics from Blender and importing them into Unreal, but I've never had this issue before.

(This animated mesh is being exported as an alembic because the animation involves a sphere being Cast through a hose over a period of time, and this is the only way I've been able to think that this could work. If there is another way this animation could be brought into Unreal, I would love to know!)

**This is the shading/smoothing that is visible in Blender, and this is what I'm hoping to achieve.**
[image: The desired shading/smoothing that I would like in Unreal]

**This is how the mesh looks in Unreal. How can I make this mesh look more like the Blender mesh?**
[image: This is the mesh quality in Unreal. How can I make this more like the Blender mesh?]

**My current alembic export settings along with the modifiers I'm using on this object.**
[image: My current alembic export settings along with the modifiers I'm using on this object.]

**My current import settings into Unreal**
[image: My current import settings into Unreal]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this is due to Unreal Engine 4's compression of the mesh.

Solution 1. You can lower the "Compressed Position Precision" value in the Unreal Engine 4 import settings to something like 0.0001. [image]

Solution 2. Another solution which I frequently do is to scale up the model when exporting from Blender. In the alembic export settings you can change the "Manual Transform > Scale" from "1.000" to "100". This will scale up your model so it is affected by less compression. I do this frequently because my blender unit length is in meters, while in Unreal the unit length is set to centimeters.
[image]